# How to deal with cv::VideoCapture decode errors?

Tags: opencv, ffmpeg, h.264, decoding, ip-camera

I'm streaming H264 content from an IP camera using the VideoCapture from OpenCV (compiled with ffmpeg support).

So far things work ok, but every once in a while I get decoding errors (from ffmpeg I presume):

```
[h264 @ 0x103006400] mb_type 137 in I slice too large at 26 10
[h264 @ 0x103006400] error while decoding MB 26 10
[h264 @ 0x103006400] negative number of zero coeffs at 25 5
[h264 @ 0x103006400] error while decoding MB 25 5
[h264 @ 0x103006400] cbp too large (421) at 35 13
[h264 @ 0x103006400] error while decoding MB 35 13
[h264 @ 0x103006400] mb_type 121 in P slice too large at 20 3
[h264 @ 0x103006400] error decoding MB 20 3
```

These messages show up in the console. Is there any clean way to listen to these ? I'd like to skip processing the glitchy frames.

Any hints/tips ?

Comment: facing the same problem.... any solution???

Answer (score 3, accepted):

recently i have solved the same problem and try to explain the steps i followed.

i updated most recent [opencv_ffmpeg.dll](https://github.com/alalek/opencv_3rdparty/tree/ffmpeg/master_20160207/ffmpeg) ( i renamed opencv_ffmpeg.dll to opencv_ffmpeg310.dll to use with OpenCV 3.1, also renamed same dll opencv_ffmpeg2412.dll to use with OpenCV 2.4.12

by doing that, a basic capturing frames and display became successful without problem.but still the same problem if i do some image-processing or detection causes delay between capturing frames.

to solve the second problem i used a thread to grab frames continiously and update a global `Mat` for processing.

[here](https://github.com/sturkmen72/opencv_samples/blob/master/rtsp/VideoCapture-thread-test.cpp)
you can find my test code ( it need some improvements like using mutex and lock memory when update the Mat)

i hope the information will be useful ( sorry for my poor english )

Comment: I haven't tried this yet, but it looks much more elegant than trying to pipe in the error messages and skip frames.

Comment: recently my approach explained by [Mare](http://study.marearts.com/2016/03/opencv-rtsp-receiving-test.html) on his blog

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem. It seems to me that the problem comes from the fact that the source originating the stream is slower than the one decoding. Probably for the decoding you have an endless loop reading frames and decoding them, which might be faster than what your source can send you.

I don't know how to stop and wait until the buffer is full .. I'm using a file, such that my camera source writes a file and I read frames from it in my decoding program. So far I haven't been able to synch them

Comment: you're right, I had an endless loop, but haven't found a solution to the problem. I was thinking about piping in the console output from opencv/ffmpeg and using frames only when no decoding errors were encountered as hacky work around, but haven't got around to implement that or find a more elegant solution

Comment: I thought about the same, but I have no idea on how to do this .. :/

Answer (score 0):

what [sturkmen](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35591041/9820874) said is absolutely right, the opencv version is 2413, and for some reason, I can not update the opencv to 310, I know there is gonna be no any decoding error like this for opencv310. So firstly, I copy lib **opencv_ffmpeg310_64.dll** to my executable file path **E:\GITHUB\JpegRtspCamera\vs2013\JpegRtspCamera\x64\Release**

then I just delete **opencv_ffmpeg2413.dll** and change the name **opencv_ffmpeg310_64.dll** to **opencv_ffmpeg2413.dll**. it works!!!