# IP camera (h.264, rstp) + GStreamer + OpenCV (Ubuntu, Jetson TK1\Desktop)

Tags: opencv, gstreamer, h.264, ip-camera

I spent a lot of time trying to find answer, but I've failed. I have an IP Camera with RTSP access (h.264). If I open the stream from OpenCV it tries to decode (as I understand) via ffmpeg and currupts frames.

```
[h264 @ 0x1821f20] error while decoding MB 3 35, bytestream -14
```

As I understood, I should use gstreamer for hardware acceleration (with NVIDIA GPU), but I can't find a real solution. What I should do?

1. run gstreamer from console and get frames from buffer (RAM?) via OpenCV app?
2. do something in OpenCV app?
3. re-compile OpenCV with gstreamer and without ffmpeg?

Comment: What is your OpenCV version?

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/a/35591041/5294258 maybe useful

Comment: I'm using OpenCV for Tegra (2.4.10) from repo

Comment: as i pointed on my answer to another question (see my comment above), maybe updating opencv_ffmpeg.dll will help. could you try and see what will happen

Answer (score 0):

Refer to the playback example for gstreamer1.0 examples in http://developer.download.nvidia.com/embedded/L4T/r21_Release_v3.0/L4T_Jetson_TK1_Multimedia_User_Guide_V2.1.pdf.

`gst-launch-1.0 filesrc location=<filename.mp4> ! qtdemux name=demux !
h264parse ! omxh264dec ! nveglglessink –e`

Instead of a file source you probably want to use the `rtspsrc` element. If you are lucky something like this may work:

`gst-launch-1.0 rtspsrc location=<rtsp://url> ! decodebin ! omxh264dec ! nveglglessink –e`

It may be that you need to manually insert rtph264depay element or others though.

If you are super lucky it may just work with something like this:

`gst-launch-1.0 playbin uri=<rtsp://url> –e`

Comment: Okay, I will test it tomorrow, but I still have questions: a) should I run this command from terminal? How to get a frame from gstreamer buffer? b) Can I use CUDA after (I mean, using 192 graphics cores for computing) decoder usage?

Comment: This is a terminal command, yes. For access to the buffer you will have to write a GStreamer application. Look into `appsink` documentation on how to do it. Why wouldn't you be able to to do some more calculation on the CUDA cores at this point?